# VSCode: git fatal error: file is outside directory

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have been using VScode for a long time, and I have used the git functionality a lot. But it has suddenly started failing. Every time I try to add a file, a single file, it says there is an error:

```
git add -A -- ""repository folder""/README.md
```

> fatal: ""repository folder""/README.md' is outside repository

I have checked the settings and there is nothing weird and also, when I add all files at once instead of just one at a time, it works well. If I add the files with the terminal's commands, it works too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use ASCII / Special chars (like æøå) in your path name this error occurs. Rename your path names / directories to the fix issue.

Be aware all parent paths for your projects directory needs to be changed, not just your paths / directories within your project.

Comment: I'm having the issue with a normal path, sans any special characters. Any ideas why VS Code would use the FQP for a simple path?

Comment: You just made my day <3 was going completely crazy

Answer (score 52):

I have got this problem after installing May 2020 VSCode update (v1.46).

After comparing git commands of the old and the new VSCode it appeared that updated VSCode uses *low case drive letter* in the path for the git command, but the old one used *upper case letter*. The `ignorecase` git option that should solve those problem was already set to `true`.

Updating git to version 2.27 solved the problem.

Comment: Update the Git for windows worked very well for me!! I use the `git update-git-for-windows`, form https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790592/how-to-upgrade-to-the-latest-version-of-git-on-windows-still-showing-older-vers#answer-55180131

Comment: Thanks! This helped me for this strange issue!

Comment: I would recommend to take a look to https://git-scm.com/download/win

and do not forget to restart the VScode ;)

Comment: I agree with @KevynTuleuDourado that https://stackoverflow.com/a/55180131/470749 was very helpful in knowing how to update Git, depending on what your current version of Git is.

Answer (score 13):

What fixed it for me was:

Being a Windows and VScode user, I fixed this by updating GIT. You do that by going to https://gitforwindows.org/ and installing.

Comment: That just happended to me, I was running an old version. Installed the latest and now it works. Cheers

Comment: I can confirm as well. Updated git from 2.10 to 2.27 and now it's working. thx!

Comment: This also fixed it for me.

Answer (score 10):

my vs code recently got updated to May 2020 release. Just after this the above git issue starting happening.
So i rollback version of my vs code to April 2020 release and now again git extension works

Comment: See @Oleg Skydan's answer. Updating to git version 2.27 may resolve issue. It did for me.

Comment: I just had the exactly same issue and this solution worked.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like the root cause mentioned in [someone else's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62382396/8641842) is correct:

> I have got this problem after installing May 2020 VSCode update (v1.46).
>
> After comparing git commands of the old and the new VSCode it appeared that updated VSCode uses low case drive letter in the path for the git command, but the old one used upper case letter.

I can see the git error complaining about `e:\...` while Windows shows `E:\...`.

Adding `ignorecase=true` didn't do it for me. Instead, I ran `git version` (which reported 2.9.x). The latest git as of writing was `2.27.y`. Upgrading git solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change my git config to get this working in my vs code.
From git version 1.6.1.9 for windows, "ignorecase=true' in config is set by default.
If you did not previously configure this in your repos you can change it to false by doing the following via your terminal in the directory with .git folder in:

> git config --local -e

Under the core options, set ignorecase to false using the text editor

> ignorecase=false

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

To users who use language other than English, this could help solving the problem.

```
git config --global core.precomposeunicode false
```

Comment: This would b a better answer if it explained _why_ this configuration change might help, and under what circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is you're trying to add something, not in the root directory which includes .git directory and sub-dirs. The file you're trying to add is outside its scope.

Don't add the file as full path. Type `git status` on your branch and just add the file.

Just do the simple thing. For example:

```
git add README.md
git commit -m "Commit message"
git checkout master
```

You can merge or rebase depending on your choice.

Comment: Yes, if I do that it works. Where it doesn't work is with the Visual Studio Code git integration

Answer (score -1):

If using: Mac OS 10 + VSCode Extension Git History 0.6.10.

Uninstalled restart VSCode reinstall Git History.

Working again.

Comment: I don't think OP mentioned he was using macOS. How can you be sure?

Comment: I added "If using" this helped me.