# git giving error about vim running in cmd

Tags: git, vim, cmd

> hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...       0 [main] vim 7372 C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vim.exe: *** fatal error - cmalloc would have returned NULL                                                                              334 [main] vim 7372 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to vim.exe.stackdump                                                                                                                                       Aborting commit due to empty commit message.

```
Note : closed all related file to the one I want to commit.
```

I am running `git commit -a` to commit all changes I did on my project. I did the hint that the cmd offer but I still get error.

How to fix above error.

`Update`

When I first run the same command I was directed to a vim and I added the comment there. This time it does go to that screen just giving the error.

Running `git status` gives me:

[image]

Comment: What does any of this have to do with GitHub?

Comment: @romainl please do remove the tag if you deem it unnecessary. I though it needs to be there since I run the git command when I got the error.

Comment: There's no GitHub tag to remove.

Comment: Do not include images of text--instead copy and paste the text directly into the question.

Comment: [How to update Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790592/how-to-upgrade-to-the-latest-version-of-git-on-windows-still-showing-older-vers/48924212#48924212)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This error message can be seen in [CMD wrapper like cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1106).

It was recently fixed in [Git for Windows 356](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/356#issuecomment-405501452) and [PR 29](https://github.com/git-for-windows/MSYS2-packages/pull/29).
It will be in [Git 2.19 (for Windows) around Sept. 9th](https://github.com/git-for-windows/MSYS2-packages/pull/29#issuecomment-411759850).

As the [OP guradio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4452553/guradio) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833906/git-giving-error-about-vim-running-in-cmd/51833958?noredirect=1#comment91130762_51833958):

> Just used VScode and now I can update Git.

Comment: im reading the fix but I cant totally understand to be honest no matter how many times I read it. Do i need to install new git?

Comment: @guradio Yes, the 2.19 as soon as it will be released. In the meantime, are you using a simple CMD, or cmder (a console emulator: http://cmder.net/)?

Comment: just a CMD in windows. Im using Visual Studio as IDE if it helps

Comment: @guradio So vim should not be involved: try and see if you can set vscode as your editor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36644561/6309. Then check if the issue persists.

Comment: @guradio Thank you for the feedback: I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 8):

I got `cmalloc would have returned NULL` when trying to launch vim from a command line in git bash through ConsoleZ. According to https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2014-07/msg00185.html, this can happen if you set your console/terminal buffer too large. I had mine set at 5000 lines. Reducing it to 2000 resolved my issue. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Finally, the real solution!  Though I do wonder how it got set to 9000 lines...either way, probably want to change the Defaults as well as the current window.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error while i was using a normal command prompt on windows. I switched to git bash and it worked like a charm!

Comment: thank you so much for this! Works great if you need a quicker fix than some proposed above.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

My environment:

- Windows 10 Version 20H2
- git version 2.33.1.windows.1

When checking the global options (`git config --global --list`) no default editor was set.

Setting the default editor to vim fixed the issue on my machine:
`git config --global core.editor vim`