# How to uninstall git-for-windows & re-install in new place?

Tags: git, uninstallation, installation-path, git-for-windows

I have updated/upgraded my installation of git-for-windows to **git version 2.19.1.windows.1** using the command line method [defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48924212/601770).

The original **install folder** was **directly in**

> C:\Users\MY_UNAME

I would like to uninstall it (**and remove all of its associated files)** from there.

**Then re-install it into a** sub-folder of

> C:\Users\MY_UNAME

say

> C:\Users\MY_UNAME\git_4win

.

How can accomplish this?

Answer (score 12):

Look for the C:\Program Files\Git\unins001.exe or similar in your install folder. It is the uninstall programme that come with Git-for-Windows.

Answer (score 6):

You can uninstall git using 3 simple steps:

Go to Start Menu > Add Or Remove Programs

In the search bar that pops up, just type Git.

Then just click on the Uninstall button and follow the uninstaller instructions!

To reinstall:

Go to https://git-scm.com/download/win and the installer will download for you. Click on the installer, and enter the custom installation directory that you wanted to install it to (`C:\Users\MY_UNAME`). Hit the 'Next' button (on the bottom left of the installer window) until you get to the final menu where you have the 'Install' button.

Click on it, and viola, you've successfully reinstalled git!

Comment: Note that there is no custom installation directory option **unless you run the install as an administrator**.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do a simple uninstall standard through Windows programs, and execute the new [`Git-2.19.1-64-bit.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.19.1.windows.1/Git-2.19.1-64-bit.exe), this time selecting a different target folder.

Personally, I prefer using [`PortableGit-2.19.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.19.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.19.1-64-bit.7z.exe), a self-extracting archive that I can uncompress anywhere I want.