# Git: Cannot spawn error and unable to fork

Tags: git, gitlab

Team,
While  I tried to push the code to the git, I am getting the following strange error.
I could not get rid of this.

```
error: cannot spawnerror: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

I tried doing the following and got the same above error:

```
git push origin master // Tried pushing to the branch
git checkout -b vettal // Tried creating a new branch and then push
git push origin master -f
git push origin master --force
```

Neither of the above commands worked

Do anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619355/trouble-pushing-to-github-cannot-spawn-sh-no-such-file-or-directory) answer your question?

Comment: But I do not know how to uninstall the git..

Comment: I dont know aby git commands to uninstall the git through git bash anyways?

Comment: Here is how you uninstall git-for-windows (git bash) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682006/how-to-uninstall-git-for-windows-re-install-in-new-place

Comment: Yes It worked. I uninstalled and reinstalled both git and gitbash and it is working. Thank you

Comment: Great! You can write an answer to it and close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following steps and it worked:

1. I deleted the .git folder
2. I uninstalled the git from c:/program files
3. I Uninstalled git bash too
4. Installed the git and git bash now
5. Initialized git

I checked using the following commands and it worked:

```
git checkout -b vettal // created a new branch 
git push origin vettal // and then made a push
```

Thanks for all the help made through various questions in stackoverflow!