# How to upgrade to GIT latest version without downloading the full setup every time?

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I really like to try the new features from **GIT** and get practiced so I'm updating my git version to the latest version frequently whenever GIT release any new versions with good features.

I'm following the regular way ([Download the full setup](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and update my GIT version) to update the GIT version but *I'm finding the way to update my GIT version without downloading full setup file and I should be able to download only the remaining part (ie, recent updates only) of the setup.*

> Also if we have an option like update GIT version by a comment or a
>   single click that will be great for GIT users to update their GIT
>   versions.

Comment: If you are using git 2.14+, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48924212/2745495.

Comment: Yes, It looks good.