# Git Bash error: fsmonitor_ipc__send_query

Tags: git, git-bash, git-for-windows

I would just like to ask what could be the meaning of this error?

```
error: fsmonitor_ipc__send_query: unspecified error on '.git/fsmonitor--daemon.ipc'
```

I'm trying to find something similar to this case but for some reason, all I see is another line error which is very similar but isn't explained why. I encountered this while I'm using Git Bash. I'm trying to utilize the Bash terminal as I want to have a different window separated when working with VS Code. Hope this become a reference for the others.

Comment: Include the name and release of your OS, and your specific Git version here. The file system monitoring code is new, highly OS-dependent, and may contain various bugs.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error here. I'm actually not using git bash, but rather Powershell, both 5.1 and 7.1.
Git Version: 2.32.0.windows.1
OS Version: Windows 10 19043.1165

Comment: After updating to Git 2.33 I do not see this message anymore.

Comment: @RamonZarazuaB. I'll try to update my Git as well. Thank you very much for informing me.

Comment: @torek I'm using Win10 x64 v.1904 while the Git vesion is 2.32. I'll try to update my git if that will solve the error. Thank you very much to all of you guys.

Comment: Same error here, but upgrade did not help. Git Version: 2.33.0. windows.  OS Version: Windows Server 2019 Standard [Version 10.0.17763.2183]. VMware Virtual Platform.

Comment: I got this error, and it appears that it was caused by git daemon process running elevated (as Administrator) but `git pull` command called from a non-elevated process. Killing daemon and restating it non-elevated fixed the issue. But it could be a coincidence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error seems to be related to a bug in Git for Windows 2.32. Upgrading to [Git for Windows 2.33](http://git-scm.com/download/win)+ has fixed it for several people.

Comment: For anyone looking on how to update their git using windows please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790592/how-to-upgrade-git-on-windows-to-the-latest-version)

Comment: I'm running git version 2.33.0.windows.2 , still get this message. I used to have core.fscache=true but now set to false but I still get this error every time I run git status

Comment: Still getting it regardless of core.fscache

Comment: I was getting this error on version 2.33.0.windows.2, updating to version 2.33.1.windows.1 fixed it.

Comment: I got it on 2.35.0.windows.1, but I did check the experimental built-in file system monitor

Answer (score 10):

I, like others have mentioned, received this error, and my current Git version is `2.32.0.windows.1`. I've been running this version for months and today was the first time I encountered the error.

**I killed all running `git.exe` processes on my machine and the error went away.**

Note that when you upgrade to a new version of Git, one of the things you have to do is stop all running processes of Git. I mention this because it might not be the case that this is a bug specific to 2.32 which is fixed in version 2.33, but instead, maybe it's simply the action of killing the running Git processes during the install that fixes the issue. I suppose a reboot may have fixed it as well.

Answer (score 3):

At first, uninstall git from your computer. Then delete the **Git** folder from *C:\Program Files*. Finally, install git again and restart your computer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.