# update git via cmd?

Tags: git, git-extensions, git-for-windows

I recently updated my Git Extension to 3.0.2.5232 and now my git is no longer supported. When I run:

```
git --version
```

I get

```
 git version 2.9.0.windows.1
```

However, I can't just download the latest version of git online because I can't run an .exe installer due to admin rights and what not, so is there a command I can run to upgrade directly from admin cmd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't run an exe due to the right restrictions, you should use the portable version ( https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases ).

Uncompress it in a folder and add the path of this folder in your `PATH` environment variable **before** the one of the old git. Or set it directly in GitExtensions.

Answer (score 41):

Yes there is.

Use the command:`git update-git-for-windows` in your cmd and press Y and will update it.

Example:

[image]

PS: I don't have any admin control. It's my company computer, so you should be able to update it too

Comment: when i try this command it says "git: 'update-git-for-windows' is not a git command. See 'git --help'."

Comment: That's only available since git v2.16.1 https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.16.1.windows.2 (and since v2.14 it was call `git update`)

Answer (score 10):

In my answer, I'll show how to update Git on Windows , Linux , MacOS.

- On **Windows** , open git command window and write

```bash
git update-git-for-windows
```

---

- On **Linux, I tested the solution on [ubuntu - KaliLinux] and work correctly** and based on [SethMMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1399279/sethmmorton) comment, it wouldn’t work on Fedora, Arch, Gentoo, or a number of other Linux flavors, to apply the solution  open your terminal and write these commands

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y
    
sudo apt-get update
    
sudo apt-get install git -y
```

After installing, you can see your new version of git with:
`git --version`

---

- On **MacOS** view this answer [update git on MacOS from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48953680/5661396)

Comment: By "Linux", you mean "Debian-based Linux systems", correct?

Comment: @SethMMorton, I tested the solution on Kali Linux and Ubuntu and I think the solution will work any other Debian-based Linux systems.

Comment: Sure, but it wouldn’t work on Fedora, Arch, Gentoo, or a number of other Linux flavors. `apt` is only for Debian, so saying those instructions are for Linux without qualifying the statement is not correct.

Answer (score 4):

Use the command:git update-git-for-windows in your git Bash console

Comment: How is this different from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55163561/5411817) posted over 9 months earlier, which was the  first answer given, and is the top voted answer. In fact while the code is the same, your post is lower quality, with less usage info, and no code highlighting.  Please review help topics in [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering). SO is designed to function different than forums are designed. Here the platform relies on answers *NOT* being *repeated*! Instead any good and useful answers should be *upvoted*. This post should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Download a portable git version (https://git-scm.com/download/win), and point GE to it via `Settings > Git > Paths`

Answer (score 0):

Go to Git Bash from Start icon
then execute command "**git --version**" and it will show Git version installed on your machine

Case 1st:

If your Git version is **2.14.1** or earlier then uninstall Git and install again from **https://git-scm.com/download/win**

Case 2nd:

If your Git version is **2.14.2 and 2.16.1** then use below command
"**git update**"

Case 3rd:
If your Git version is 2.16.2 or later then use below command
"**git update-git-for-windows**"

Hope this helps.
Happy Learning
Thanks.