# Firebase initialization commands not working with catalina

Tags: macos, firebase, terminal, cocoapods, macos-catalina

I am doing pod init for a new Xcode project of mine but it fails outputting:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    5: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    4: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:49:in `run'
    1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:130:in `verify_minimum_git_version!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:118:in `git_version': Failed to extract git version from `git --version` ("xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun\n") (RuntimeError)
```

I have always done this before and never had problems with the terminal since recently updating my mac too latest version.

Comment: I solved my problem by reinstalling Git with Homebrew. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957862/how-to-upgrade-git-to-latest-version-on-macos

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9271