# Why am I getting fatal: Authentication failed for <repo URL>

Tags: git, github, clone, git-clone

I just got started on Github again, and created a new repo.  It's a private repo, so I use  `git clone <URL_clone_link>`, and it prompts for username and password (both of which I've verified are correct), but ends with the fatal error in the Title.

I'm using a terminal on a relatively new iMac, and it doesn't seem to be a local machine issue.  I just don't understand why it won't authenticate me using the same username/pwd I use to log in.

Comment: Do you have two-factor authentication enabled?

Comment: I do have 2FA enabled, yes.

Answer (score 1):

First, check that, as commented, you have [2FA activated](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/configuring-two-factor-authentication).
If yes, the password to enter would be a PAT (Personal Access Token) that you would need [to generate](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) and [add to your tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens).

Second, check your `git config credential.helper` output: if `osxkeychai`y, you might need to do:

```
 git credential-osxkeychain erase https://github.com
```

In order to remove the password cached by the `osxkeychain` credential caching setup.

Comment: Thanks - I will give this a shot and let you know if this worked (waiting on verification code for fallback SMS.. not very quick)

Comment: The `osxkeychain` value was there after running `git config credential.helper`.  I ran the erase command you mentioned, it's been sitting here running for about 10 minutes now, is this typical?  

Will update here if it finishes and I can try another clone.

Comment: I can't post I pic in the comments.. but the cursor is just sitting on the next line in the terminal, like it's trying to do what I asked but is just taking forever.

Comment: The erase command should take less than a second to execute. What version of git are you using?

Comment: `git version 2.17.0`

Comment: Is it possible for you to upgrade to git 2.26, and see if the issue persists?

Comment: Will give it a shot. I wonder if I can use home brew to update, or just download the latest from git-scm.com?

Comment: @pbkac `brew` works, provided you add a `brew link`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60696298/6309 (same as in https://medium.com/@katopz/how-to-upgrade-git-ff00ea12be18)

Comment: `brew` worked awesome, now on `git version 2.26.0`.  Quit and re-opened the terminal to run that command, because it froze up again after I updated.  Tried running it again and ... same thing.  Not sure what my Mac is trying to do .. I'm assuming I don't need `sudo` to run any git commands.

Comment: @pbkac Strange. So `git credential-osxkeychain erase https://github.com` is frozen?

Comment: Yeah... even after a restart and a recent Mac OSX update. Cursor just sits and blinks on the next line.