# Problem updating Git on my Mac using VScode

Tags: git, macos, powershell, visual-studio-code, homebrew

So basically i'm tryiing to update git on my Mac, i'm using VScode with one of the terminals propped up as powershell, and so i check the version of it using the command

```
git --version
```

What I got from it was

```
git version 2.15.0
```

So I had assumed that I hadn't updated it so I went along and used the command

```
brew upgrade git
```

and I get a response saying `"Warning: git 2.34.1 already installed"`, and I check up on it again and the git version is still at 2.15.0

Any thoughts on how I could fix this?

Comment: The root of the problem is that `brew install` installs an *additional* Git version, so now you have both Git 2.15.0 and Git 2.34.1. This means you must direct whatever is going to run `git` to look for the brew-installed version *first*, before looking for the system-installed version. As [VonC answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70782497/1256452), there are multiple ways to make this happen.

Answer (score 5):

Hey guys thank you for all those who commented what to do and what's going on, so ultimately while playing around with it for a while this was what I was able to do!

So I go into my terminal and ran `brew install git`

After that I got this reply in the terminal as follows

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.34.1... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/git
Target /usr/local/bin/git
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/git'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite git

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run git
```

So I went and ran the command

```
brew link --overwrite git
```

The reply i got was :

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.34.1... 213 symlinks created.
```

Ran the following command afterwards

```
brew link --overwrite --dry-run git
```

Got the following reply back :

> Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.34.1
>
> To relink, run:
> brew unlink git && brew link git

So I finally ran a check to see what the git version was

```
git --version
```

And I got the updated git version I was trying to get my path aligned to!

```
git version 2.34.1
```

Hope this helps anyone else who needs help with this! I did not remove '/usr/local/bin/git' but hopefully I didn't need to or won't have to worry about it later on.

Comment: It' 's brilliant, it works even when I had the PATH exported correctly to the latest version and still fail to get it.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make sure `homebrew/bin` folder is first in your $PATH (on macOS Monterey):

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

Then a `git --version` would return the expected latest version.
You have [various options explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8957862/6309), like adding `alias git="/usr/local/bin/git"` to your `.zshrc` or `.bashrc`.

Comment: When i enter the command im given a reply of "export: The term 'export' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Comment: @JahanzebAhmad First, make sure you have a macOS Monterey. Second, that line is to be added to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`. Then open a new session and launch VSCode, in order for that IDE to inherit from the new PATH.